# Rerunning Recycler set-up gives empty Recycler

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

In my `FireStore` `Recycler` `Java Android` app, I want to display the `documents` of a `collection` ordered differently depending on whether `displayList = false` or `displayList = true` is set. That boolean value is changed by the user clicking a `buttonView` in the same activity. The same click then executes the method `setUpRecyclerView()` (see code below), to "refresh" the  `Recycler`.

The app starts up with `displayList = false`. As the method `setUpRecyclerView()` is also run in `onCreate()`, the `Recycler` shows all the `documents` ordered according to `"categoryNumber"`. Perfect.

However, when the `buttonView` is clicked (changes to `displayList = true`), the `Recycler` turns empty. Also, after again clicking (changing to the original state of `displayList = false`), the `Recycler` remains empty. Still, the `Log.d` expressions indicate that the `if {} else {}` expression has been properly run through after both clicks, without any error messages.

It's as if `setUpRecyclerView()` can only be run once, at the start of the activity.

Please advise.

```
 private void setUpRecyclerView(){

    if (!displayList) {

        Query query = collectionRef
                .orderBy("categoryNumber", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);                

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Item> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Item>()
                .setQuery(query,Item.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new ItemAdapter(options);

        Log.d(TAG, "setUpRecyclerView: list false");

    } else {

        Query query = collectionRef                  
                .orderBy("itemName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Item> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Item>()
                .setQuery(query,Item.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new ItemAdapter(options);

        Log.d(TAG, "setUpRecyclerView: list true");

    }

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener() { ... }
```

Comment: Please show use the code for `buttonView` and how you set the click listener.

Comment: Hi Alex. The click listener of the buttonView works fine, as after clicking the correct Log.d shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by upon clicking restarting the whole activity, instead of only `setUpRecyclerView()`. Not very elegant, but it works.